# What is this display connection?

Tags: connector, identification, display

This is a 40 pin display connector that was found on a mass promotion video player mailed to a house. I disassembled it and I would like to use the display for a project.

The display has the model numbers JTM 50008W12-A. The flexible circuit board has the part number JTM050N-3047.

[image: this connector]

Comment: Most likely a 24 bit RGB "TTL" interface. The pinout usually doesn't follow any standard. Without the datasheet, you are lost.

Comment: Your best bet would be to identify the chip on the original main board that was driving this interface and see whether any data is available on that.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered unlikely that one 40 pin TTL LCD interface is just like another.  Both the electrical and the timing have to be considered.  That said, [this LCD TTL break out board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1932) may help.

Assuming you want to interface the screen to a Raspberry Pi, [consider this LCD TTL interface board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2454). However, again, it is considered unlikely  that one 40 pin TTL LCD interface is just like another.

In addition, you will need to make software modifications to the Raspberry Pi operating system.  Interfacing directly with a 40 pin TTL LCD will both consume nearly all your GPIO pins as well as some of your processor power.  The instructions for the software modifications are linked to [this web page](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-dpi-display-kippah-ttl-tft/overview).

Finally, consider buying a 40 pin TTL LCD that is known to work with a particular interface board.